# Rails is autoloading association from console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have 2 models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :employee, dependent: :destroy
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

and I noticed that when I call `User.last` from the console, I get the following:

```
> User.last
  User Load (3.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  User Load (3.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  Employee Load (9.3ms)  SELECT  "employees".* FROM "employees" WHERE "employees"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 21198]]
  Employee Load (9.3ms)  SELECT  "employees".* FROM "employees" WHERE "employees"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 21198]]
#<User:0x0055bd0ae9af30> { ... }
```

Why is the employee record being loaded?

Comment: Maybe `User#inspect` or `User#to_s` uses data from `employee`?

Comment: Have you tried `User.first` also?  xD

Comment: It only happens when I run the heroku console: `heroku run rails c`, not the local console

Comment: @7urkm3n I have tried that.  Same result